# Nodejs server unable to detect connection with Pubnub+SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, pubnub

My nodejs server is unable to detect when a new browser connects ('connection' event) and I dont know why. I narrowed down a problem working on it for a few days and suspect that is has to due with the addition of the pubnub socket connection implemented on the browser.

The following is my server.js

```
var http    = require('http')
  , connect = require('connect')
  , io      = require('socket.io')
  , fs      = require('fs')
  , uuid    = require('node-uuid')
  , _       = require('lodash');

// pubnub!!! (how to initialize it for use on server)
var pubnub  = require('pubnub').init({
   channel:        "my_channel",
   publish_key:    "pub-key",
   subscribe_key:  "sub-c-key",
   uuid:           "Server",
   origin : 'pubsub.pubnub.com'
});  

pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: 'my_channel',
    callback: function(message) {
      console.log("Message received: ", message);
    },
    message:  'Server ready',
    presence: function(data) {
      console.log("Presense: ", data);
    },
    connect:   publish
});

// various socket.on() events omitted

var app = connect().use(connect.static(__dirname)).use(connect.directory(__dirname));
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8888);
io = io.listen(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', handleNewPeer);
```

Upon arriving on the html page, the doConnect(isBroadcaster) function is ran from script tag

The doConnect function (In peer.js):

```
var doConnect = function(isBroadcaster) {

  console.log("doConnect");
  // broadcaster or normal peer
  var user;
  if (isBroadcaster) 
    user = "Broadcaster";
  else 
    user = "Viewer";

  (function() {
  var pubnub_setup = {
    channel:       "my_channel",
    publish_key:   "pub-c-key",
    subscribe_key: "sub-c-key",
    user:          user
  };

  // Note removed the var
  socket = io.connect( 'http://pubsub.pubnub.com', pubnub_setup);

 // various socket.on() omitted

 })();
```

Here is what how it was before with just socketIO & it was working:

```
var doConnect = function(isBroadcaster) {
  socket = io.connect();
// various socket.on() omitted 
}
```

My p2p video website is implemented with WebRTC running on a Nodejs + SocketIO server. 
I have been trying to incorporate pubnub into it & thought it would be easy since pubnub supports SocketIO (or at least client side?). Really did not think it would be this difficult to set up server side.

Any input at all on this? I think it's something simple that I just cannot put my finger on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Socket.IO on the Server using Node.JS

Socket.IO with PubNub does not provide a Node.JS Socket.IO backend option.  However you can use the PubNub SDK directly for on-connect events.

#### NPM Package

```
npm install pubnub
```

After you install the PubNub NPM you can use the node.js server backend:

#### Node.js Backend Code

```
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// PubNub!!! (how to initialize it for use on server)
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
var pubnub = require('pubnub').init({
   publish_key   : "pub-key",
   subscribe_key : "sub-c-key",
   uuid          : "Server-ID"
});  

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// On user Connect
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
function on_user_connect(data) {
  console.log( "User Connected: ", data.uuid );
}

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// On user Leave
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
function on_user_leave(data) {
  console.log( "User Left: ", data.uuid );
}

// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
// Open Socket Connection for User Join Events
// -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel  : 'my_channel',
    connect  :   connected
    message  : function(message) {
      console.log("Message received: ", message);
    },
    presence : function(data) {
      if (data.action == "leave")   on_user_leave(data);
      if (data.action == "timeout") on_user_leave(data);
      if (data.action == "join")    on_user_connect(data);
    }
});

function connected() {
  console.log('connected!');
}
```

Comment: hmm that kind of inconvenient on my side since I really only need the server to detect a connection of a peer when they hit the html page. Does pubnub plan to add future back end support?

Comment: I tried using the pubnub presence future but I still got to run a few more tests. Right now it seems when the server is ran 3 presence are automatically detected (even when no one is on the site) and when there is 1 broadcaster & 1 viewer, their presence share the same uuid for some reason (is uuid Ip or mac address based?) I even tried hardcoding a different uuid for them but no luck

Comment: @JerryFox Hi again.  yes you will be detecting your server as a connection.  If you want to exclude the server you can subtract the `occupancy` by the number you feel is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What version of socket.io are you using?

This might not fix it. I am using version 1.+ Have you tried:

```
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        console.log('user connected');
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the input! I was really hoping this would help but it seems the issue is something completely different

Comment: Sorry about that. Good luck. I got some issues with socket.io too at the moment.